# Is it possible to get the account id when i click on New Action in Account

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I need some help to get the account id When i click on New Action in Account 
Step 1: I have created one New Action in Account with the Action type is Visualforce Page.
Step 2: When i click on the this action in mobile i am showing the Visualforce Page in this visualforce page i need the account id.

Is it Possible?

Thanks,
Singaiah.Ch

Comment: Account Ids don't exist on New action until the Account is saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Account specific action, then your apex page should use `standardController="Account"`, then you can use `{! Account.Id }` to get the Id of related Account record.